# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line

Tags: android, android-layout

when I made ​​several successive actions and very fast on my application
, i found problem like:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line#38
```

or

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line#39
```

or

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line#2
```

and all this problem is set by:

```
setContentView(R.layout.XXX);
```

but in normal way, I have'nt problem

have you some idea about this problem

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

you are using **ViewFlipper ?**

**ViewFlipper** loads all images into memory during layout inflating. Because my images are big it takes many memory,so you can used **ImageSwicher** instead of viewFlipper.

If you are used ImageSwitcher then it load only one image at a time so you can resolve your problem.